# Request: cleaning Super User from a particular spam for password recovery tools

Tags: discussion, spam

This morning came an advertising user for some password recovery products for Windows. It was obvious spam, and was reported as such, and deleted.

However, [searching for their "product"](http://www.google.fr/search?q=site%3Asuperuser.com++%22Windows+Password+Key%22) shows that this is something frequent, that they are coming back often with anonymous accounts.

Could we have a massive cleaning from moderators of the existing ones?

Is there something else to do about it, since it seems recurring and not all of them are seen on time?

---

**Edit:** Ok, it seems that it was cleaned each time, but the google search is not up to date, simply, as most of the links on it direct to deleted answers. The question about the recurring effect stays, though.

Comment: So Google has to clean up their trash bin ;-)

Comment: Thanks for pointing them out, Gnoupi. It's been fun destroying those users.

Comment: Also, when you're at 10k on SU, look at the horror of this: http://superuser.com/questions/95685/windows-7-administrator-password/

Comment: @random: ....wow....

Comment: @random - sure, mock me with your moderation tools when you have even less reputation than me, with a "come back with 10k", I appreciate :P

Comment: It would be funny if a mod suspended themselves and just carried on with their normal duties, but showing up as a 1 rep user.

Comment: @random that's the kind of idea which pushes Jeff not to make you a moderator on Meta.

Comment: Well that sounds about right. @gno

Comment: ...while posting a screen capture would be quite easy. ;-)

Comment: And so the request has been made and spammed up plenty. @arj

Comment: One which isn't cleaned: http://superuser.com/questions/267306/i-have-a-laptop-with-windows-vista-and-when-i-try-to-connect-to-the-local-shared

Answer (score 4):

Witness, the horror that is a question set up specifically for the spammers to talk to each other:

[image: super spammers]

Mods do go about deleting these, but it's also good if the community flags anything they think might be spam to help the process.

Comment: Impressive work!

Comment: +1 for showing off our "hard work" to the community :P

Answer (score 1):

We do have a global blacklist and anything extra-egregious goes on it.

If you feel a term (typically, URLs are best) is occuring in evil/spam posts enough to warrant inclusion on the blacklist, please email to team@superuser.com (or the appropriate team@site email).

This is something one of the developers has to do at the moment, because the global blacklist is really dangerous if you get it wrong.. like, if, say, you accidentally added a bad regex to it that blocks a common word..

Comment: As an aside... http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2009/01/this-site-may-harm-your-computer-on.html :-)

Comment: As for the Google results being outdated: I assume the bots get some `410 Gone` for deleted answers?