# Can we please blacklist the computersight.com Spam (if possible)?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, spam, blacklist

As most of you will have noticed, the last two days brought us enormous amounts of spam from `computersight.com` – more specifically the following link:

```
computersight.com / communication-networks / security / the-menace-of-win-32-virus
```

I don't have a count of the posts / users already deleted, but i suspect it's in the upper twenties?

Jeff [said](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59748/how-to-deal-with-persistent-spam-users/59751#59751) [before](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/924/request-cleaning-super-user-from-a-particular-spam-for-password-recovery-tools/925#925):

> We do have a global blacklist and anything extra-egregious goes on it.

Even more so, [just recently](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106578/users-systematically-spamming-the-site-with-a-specific-url/106579#106579) (emphasis mine):

> […] I am open to blacklisting URLs if there is indeed a **recurring pattern of abuse**, but blacklisting isn't worth it unless there is a demonstrated pattern of this specific URL appearing **at least on two different incidents**.

Wouldn't it be about time adding this website (and the IPs they are using, if trackable) to our blacklist? I sure appreciate the free flag weight, but we probably have other things to do than just downvote, spam-flag and delete questions, answers and users all day.

---

**Update:** *[They are back](https://superuser.com/questions/338146/how-to-play-2-wmv-files-in-sync-on-windows/338154#338154), aaaah!*

Comment: There was one valid mention of computersight.com, I proposed an edit to that answer to use `[text](link)` so that searching for `computersight.com` would no longer turn up that post. Hopefully preventing it from being removed by an overzealous reader of this post :P

Comment: Heh. Yes, I've seen that too while going spam-hunting! Maybe restrict it to the specific URL for the time being?

Comment: Given that they're now spamming that URL a lot, I think replacing the one previous legitimate reference to it with a better article from a site that doesn't spam us would be appropriate. I asked Jeff in the [related meta.so post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/106578/139837) to add the URL to the blacklist.

Comment: And, it sounds like it's been done.

Comment: Down with the spammers!

Comment: @MatthewRead that doesn't stop anyone using a URL search to find it. Edit: hmmm, stupid comment markdown doesn't parse the `*`'s properly, use `http://superuser.com/search?q=url%3A*computersight.com*` or search on SU for `url:*computersight.com*` and you'll see the point I was trying to make...

Comment: That web site is plastered with advertisements, music, and a persistent pop-up bar the covers a big section of the top of the page.  It looks like an attempt at copying SuperUser.com, but with advertising all over the place.  I'm suspicious of spammers because their goal is usually to find a system to exploit so they can push their scams on to large audiences -- any user accounts that post spam should just be deleted to prevent them from gaining any useful points (just imagine a spammer with access to moderator tools!).

Comment: @RandolfRichardson Those accounts have all been deleted. It's not hard to post on the SE sites without registration though, so there's no real barrier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is now [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).  `computersight.com` has been blackballed out of existence, their accounts and credentials destroyed.